# Adding an Attachment to Contact Form Using wp_mail

Tags: wp-mail

Would anyone be kind enough to explain to me how to attach an uploaded file to an email generated using wp_mail? I've built the form but all the questions I can find online refer to attaching a pre-determined file rather than one uploaded by the user.

EDIT
I'm now trying to use wp_handle_upload:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
if ( $movefile ) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
  var_dump( $movefile);
} else {
  echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

...but am getting the following error: "File is empty. Please upload something more substantial..." Which I think is because I'm not passing the attachment variable in correctly.

My form field looks like:

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_picture">
```

Could anyone point out how I tie these two together please?

Comment: You can check out the form in use at http://salt.nugerama.co.uk/jobs/

Comment: Is this related to Wordpress?

Comment: Yes Gangesh. It's a template for a WordPress theme with a contact for on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, I was simply failing to pass in the correct variable:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

$uploadedfile       = $_FILES['uploaded_file'];
$upload_overrides   = array( 'test_form' => false );
$movefile           = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

if( $movefile ) {
    //echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    //var_dump( $movefile);
    $attachments = $movefile[ 'file' ];
    wp_mail($to, $subject, strip_tags($message), $headers, $attachments);
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

My form field should have been:

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" accept="application/pdf">
```

Comment: Great that you could solve the problem! Please mark your answer as solved using the ✔.

Comment: it seems that it should not work becuase at you html the name of input is not `file`. Or at your php code you should replace `file` to `uploaded_file`